# How to add double commands so it gives decimal average

Tags: java, decimal

I am trying to make code that averages 3 inputted tests scores with decimals. When i put in the double command it gives me an error. it works well without the double command but when i try to add it it just doesnt work, ive tried to look online but cant find anything. Please help

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class FirstLab
{
    public static void main(String[] args) //header of the main method
    {
  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        int test1 , test2 , test3;

        int double NUM_TEST= 3;

        System.out.print("Input first test: "); // user prompt
        test1 = in.nextInt(); // read in the next integer

        System.out.print("Input second test: "); // user prompt
        test2 = in.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Input third test: "); // user prompt
        test3 = in.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Average test score is: " +
   (test3 + test2 + test1) / double(NUM_TEST);

  }
}


this is the error message:

C:\Users\Guestt\Desktop\CSE\FirstLab.java:18: error: not a statement
        int double NUM_TEST= 3;
        ^
C:\Users\Guestt\Desktop\CSE\FirstLab.java:18: error: ';' expected
        int double NUM_TEST= 3;
           ^
C:\Users\Guestt\Desktop\CSE\FirstLab.java:30: error: '.class' expected
   (test3 + test2 + test1) / double(NUM_TEST);
                                   ^
C:\Users\Guestt\Desktop\CSE\FirstLab.java:30: error: ';' expected
   (test3 + test2 + test1) / double(NUM_TEST);
                                    ^
C:\Users\Guestt\Desktop\CSE\FirstLab.java:30: error: illegal start of expression
   (test3 + test2 + test1) / double(NUM_TEST);
                                            ^
5 errors

Tool completed with exit code 1
```

Comment: A variable can be an `int` or a `double`, but not both.  If you want it to be a `double`, then remove the `int`.  Also, read up about integer division.

Comment: it still doesnt give me an average with a decimal is there anyway you can help?

Comment: `double NUM_TEST= 3;` not `int double NUM_TEST= 3;` and `System.out.println("Average test score is: " + (test3 + test2 + test1) / NUM_TEST);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, the variable `NUM_TEST` is declared as `int double`; simply writing `double` is sufficient.

Also, in the last print statement, there is an unmatched left parenthesis; it is also enough to reference the variable name `NUM_TEST` instead of writing `double(NUM_TEST)`

The following code is slightly fixed and should work:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int test1 , test2 , test3;
double NUM_TEST= 3;
System.out.print("Input first test: "); // user prompt
test1 = in.nextInt(); // read in the next integer
System.out.print("Input second test: "); // user prompt
test2 = in.nextInt();
System.out.print("Input third test: "); // user prompt
test3 = in.nextInt();
System.out.println("Average test score is: " + (test3 + test2 + test1) / (NUM_TEST));
```

:)